# Drop rows in a dataframe based on type of the entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe `x` that has a column `terms`. Terms are supposed to be of type string, but some contain numbers and for this reason I want to delete the rows in the dataframe where the corresponding `terms` values are integers/floats. I tried the following but received a `Key Error`:

```
x = x.drop(x[type(x['terms']) is int].index)
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: Would you want to drop `'12'` also? I mean numbers as string.

Comment: good point. It is worth a check for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'terms': [13, 0.23, 'hello', 'world', '12', '0.45']})
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['terms'], errors='coerce').isna()]
print(df)

# Output:
   terms
2  hello
3  world
```

Details:

```
>>> df
   terms
0     13
1   0.23
2  hello
3  world
4     12
5   0.45

>>> pd.to_numeric(df['terms'], errors='coerce')
0    13.00
1     0.23
2      NaN
3      NaN
4    12.00
5     0.45
Name: terms, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'sd','sf',2,5,'13','s','143f','d234f','z24']})
#            notice 13 is a string here ^^^^

       a
0      1
1     sd
2     sf
3      2
4      5
5     13
6      s
7   143f
8  d234f
9    z24
```

If you want to get rid of items that *look like numbers* but are actually strings, use this:

```py
df = df[~df['a'].astype(str).str.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
       a
1     sd
2     sf
6      s
7   143f
8  d234f
9    z24
```

If you want to get rid of items that are actually not strings at all, use this:

```py
df = df[df['a'].transform(type).eq(str)]
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
       a
1     sd
2     sf
5     13  <--- Notice how the string '13' is kept
6      s
7   143f
8  d234f
9    z24
```

Comment: This is a great answer, nonetheless the numbers could also be floating points and not just natural numbers.